# Multiple has_many relationships to the same class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many

I'm building a football game and I'm having trouble creating Club and Match classes. I want to be able to do this:

```
match = Match.find(2)
match.home_club = <some club here>
match.away_club = <other club here>
```

And also this:

```
club = Club.find(2)
club.matches # Returns all matches where club plays home or away
```

This is what I have now:

```
class Club < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :matches
end

class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :home_club, :class_name => "Club"
  belongs_to :away_club, :class_name => "Club"
end
```

But when I try to do `Club.first.matches`, I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: matches.club_id: SELECT "matches".* FROM "matches" WHERE ("matches".club_id = 1)
```

I have played around with `:inverse_of` but I didn't get it working. Is it even possible like this, or do I need to have two separate `:has_many` relationships in Club? Like this:

```
class Club < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :home_matches, :class_name => "Match"
  has_many :away_matches, :class_name => "Match"
end
```

I tried this too, but it didn't work either.

Comment: Did you get this solved?

Answer (score 0):

You are building a many-to-many relationship, so you'll need a link table. Rather then having foreign keys in either of your entity tables, this table stores those relationships, and should  have nothing but a match_id and a club_id to associate the two tables. You can then use

```
class Club < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :matches, :through => :matches_clubs
end
```

etc.

See more here 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: This would allow me to do `match.clubs`, but not `match.home_club` and `match.away_club`..

Comment: the relation isnt really n-m is it? its clearly 2-n, I suppose it isnt a normal relation to define but a table for only the relation is a bit much?

Comment: It's a pretty standard pattern. You can then also add various information on the match up in the link table. Home or away. What color they wore that day. etc.

Comment: That said, if there's really only two clubs per match always, then multiple foreign keys might make more sense

Answer (score 0):

Did you define the relation in your schema as `home_club_id` and `away_club_id`? Because it seems rails is trying to get `match.club_id` which clearly conflicts with the model you require

I think your model is wrong and should be revised.
Clubs should not have a `match_id`.

Match should be:

- home_club_id
- away_club_id
- time
- score

Club should be:

- name
- city

I think if you remove the belongs to from clubs you should be fine.

If you want to be able to do `club.matches`.
You might have to write a custom sql query that looks in both the home_club and away_club columns. Or make a relation table for clubs -> match that has a extra metafield saying if the club was home or away. While you have the home and away clubs in your match table

Comment: Yes, they're defined as `home_club_id` and `away_club_id`. How can I tell Rails to look for `home_club_id` when I access `home_club`?

Comment: has_one :away_club, :class_name => "Club", :foreign_key => :away_club_id